# Pass current view into the FullCalendar JSON feed url

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a calendar like this defined:

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'list' ],
      defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
      events: '/activities/calendar.json?view=' + 'dayGridMonth',  //calendarEl.view.title,
```

I am trying to customize the events JSON feed to the view - way easier to do this on the server side then adding a bunch of JavaScript logic.  All I want to do is append the current view to the json url.  In my code above I just manually coded `'dayGridMonth'` but looking to make it dynamic.  Tried `calendarEl.view.title` but that returns `undefined`.  Read the docs but can't make sense of this.  Perhaps I am looking at this the wrong way.

Comment: "All I want to do is append the current view"...you can't. This has been asked before a few times. If the view is changing (e.g. user moves from month to week view), the event feed URL will be called in parallel to the view rendering code. So even if you can get fullCalendar to tell you to the "current" view, it'll almost certainly be the "previous" one in reality, because the new one won't have rendered (and updated fullCalendar's internal state) yet.

Comment: More interesting is why you want to send that to the server? What are you going to do differently based on that?? The views are just different ways of looking at the same periods of time, so you'd return the same set of events (for the relevant time period) no matter what type of view it is. I'm not sure I understand the use case here.